# Wordpress post order when using $count to display posts in columns

Tags: wordpress, posts

I’m using this code to display wordpress posts in divs with specific classes. Is there a way to get the posts in a random order and still do this? I’ve searched and can’t find anything that has helped me figure this out. Thanks.

```
<?php $count = 0; if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post() ?>    

<div class="grid4 noall
<?php if( $count%3 == 0 ) { echo 'first'; }; if( $count%3 == 1 ) { echo 'mid'; }; if( $count%3 == 2 ) { echo 'last'; }; $count++; ?>">

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('clearfix'); ?> role="article">

<a class="plink" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="    <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
<section class="portfolio-wrapper">

<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumb-800' ); ?>

<div class="portfolio-title">
<h3 class="portfolio-header"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

<?php if( get_field('portfolio_subtitle') ): ?>
<h5 class="portfolio-category">
<?php the_field('portfolio_subtitle'); ?>
</h5>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>

</section>
</a>

</article>

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Can you display the whole loop here so I can see your current query?

Comment: I’ve updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Is this in the main WordPress loop, or are you running a custom query with WP_Query? If the latter, you could just simply pass the 'orderby' => 'rand' parameter in your arguments array. If it's in the main WordPress loop, the answer's slightly different, but similar. Essentially, you'd want to apply the set_query_var function to the main loop, conditionally depending on which page / view you're working with.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_query_var

for instance,

```
if(is_post_type_archive('products')){
    set_query_var('orderby','rand');
}
```

Comment: It’s the main loop, I’ll also want to use it on the archive page.